# Зал или зала, рельс или рельса, санаторий или санатория?

Tags: орфография, выбор-слов, орфоэпия

Как правильно надо произносить эти слова?

Comment: Речь идет не только о произношении, но и о написании.

Answer (score 2):

Сегодня в словарях отмечаются как правильные только первые формы. Вторые формы уже считаются устаревшими. Однако еще XIX веке такие формы не считались устаревшими.

**Большая зала (А. Серафимович, А. Н. Толстой), новая санатория (М. Горький, А. Новиков-Прибой), правая рельса (И. Бунин).**

Answer (score 2):

Первоначально вопрос (до правки) был таким:
*Как правильно надо **говорить**: Зал или зала, рельс или рельса, санаторий или санатория?*

**1.1.** **зал**, -а, м. и (*устар*.) *ЗАЛА*, -ы, ж.
1. Помещение для публики, публичных собраний, для занятий чем-нибудь, для размещения экспонатов (в музее).
*Зрительный зал. Актовый зал. Спортивный зал. В залах музея.*
2. ожидания (для пассажиров).
3. Парадная комната для приема гостей.

С. И. Ожегов, Н. Ю. Шведова. Толковый словарь русского языка.

**1.2.** ЗА́ЛА, залы, жен. (разг.).
То же, что зал.
*Зевал средь модных и старинных зал* (А. С. Пушкин).

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940

**2.** **рельс**
Существительное, неодушевлённое, мужской род.
Встречается также просторечный вариант написания: рельса, рельсина.

**3. санаторий**
Существительное, неодушевлённое, мужской род.
Стационарное учреждение для лечения и профилактики заболевания, а также для отдыха.

Однако, Георгий Иванов в рассказе «Карменсита» пишет:
*Я жил в доме отдыха, осенью, в Петергофе в 1920 году. Я пользовался **этой пролетарской санаторией** впервые и, признаюсь, с удовольствием. Даже больше, с некоторым ощущением «волшебного сна»...*
[**Дворец "Бельведер"**](http://www.citywalls.ru/house24219.html)

Однако, есть рассказ Саши Чёрного [**"Кошачья санатория" (1924 г.)**](http://librebook.me/koshachia_sanatoriia/vol1/1).

В современном русском литературном языке нормативными являются существительные **зал, рельс, санаторий** (мужского рода).

Есть мнение, отличное от общепринятого:
*Когда-то говорили и писали: **зала, мотоциклетка, фильма, санатория.** Теперь говорят и пишут: зал, мотоцикл, фильм, санаторий. И даже говоря о женщине, пишущей стихи, именуют ее не поэтессой, а поэтом. Чем вызвано это омужчиниванье речи?*
[Вадим Шефнер. ИЗ ЗАПИСНОЙ КНИЖКИ ВАСИЛЕОСТРОВЦА](http://a-pesni.org/dvor/piter/a-izzapisn.php)